# Query works if I don't bind, but fails when I do. Where is my error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tried variations of this:

```
$prep_get_company=$connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM sl_customer WHERE company_name = ':company_name'");
$prep_get_company->bindParam(':company_name',$company_name);
```

and I get no results but if I do this:

```
$prep_get_company=$connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM sl_customer WHERE company_name = '$company_name'");
```

It returns my desired results. The contents of `$company_name` is a string with spaces.

Comment: remove the single quotes on your query, not needed **and could be the issue it fails.** The prepared statement will by itself arrange the value as needed.

Comment: ...meaning this => `':company_name'` to `:company_name` in `WHERE company_name = ':company_name'");`

Comment: Nope remove single quotes from WHERE stement. WHERE company_name = ':company_name' to WHERE company_name = :company_name . This probably will fix issue, if wont. Paste error log here.

Comment: @MehmetDursunInce that is exactly what fred and I pointed so not sure why you have a `Nope` at the start.

Comment: @Prix I said it for second command but I see now I misunderstood Fred's answers. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes on your query:

```
SELECT * FROM sl_customer WHERE company_name = ':company_name'
```

Should have been:

```
SELECT * FROM sl_customer WHERE company_name = :company_name
```

The single quote will treat it as a literal value which would make your prepared statement fail to bind as it think there is nothing to bind when using the single quotes.

The prepared statement will by itself arrange the data you're binding to it as needed.

Comment: I thought that was how I tried it the first time, and only added them as an attempt to fix it, so I must have had a different error. Your suggestion worked. Thank you!